# IE and replaceWith not preserving radio button state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into an issue regarding replaceWith not maintaining the state of a moved radio button input. I've prepared a simple example illustrating this issue. This works in FF and Chrome, but not IE.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/unola4/2

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>IE replaceWith issue</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#temp').replaceWith($('#window').children());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='#'>run replaceWith</a>
  <p>Select a radio button and then click "run replaceWith". The value persists in FF, but not IE.</p>
  <div id='window' style='background-color: #DDD; height: 100px;'>
    <input id="id_received_date-days_0" type="radio" name="received_date-days" value="30" />
    <input id="id_received_date-days_1" type="radio" name="received_date-days" value="50" />
    <input type='text' name='test-test' />
  </div>
  <br />
  <form id='foo' style='background-color: #EEE'>
    <div id='temp'></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the IDs of the checked ones, then check them again after replacing:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkedOnes = $("#window input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    $('#temp').replaceWith($('#window').children());
    $.each(checkedOnes, function(index, value) {
        $("#" + value).attr("checked", "checked"); 
    });
});
```

Also, you're ending up with duplicate IDs when you copy those elements. I'm assuming you remove the old ones after the replace? Could duplicate IDs be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Doesn't replaceWith move the elements (as in add and remove), not clone?

The example in the replaceWith docs states: "From this example, we can see that the selected element replaces the target by being moved from its old location, not by being cloned."